# Android-Java Can't write to firebase Realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm unable to write into my database, I've looked at tutorial videos and changed it to look like theirs each time but it still won't write. I have the database read and write rules set to true. Here is my Gradle dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.2'
```

In the AndroidManifest.xml I have the Internet permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Here is the code that is trying to write to the database:

```
private EditText editTextUsername, editTextPhone;
private Button buttonSave;

private FirebaseDatabase db;
public DatabaseReference databaseReference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

   // firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    editTextUsername = findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
    editTextPhone = findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
    buttonSave = findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);

    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = db.getReference();



    buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString();
            databaseReference.setValue(username);
        }
    });

}
```

I'm not getting any errors but it won't send to the database, I've checked the button and that works.

Comment: Add listeners to `setValue()` and try checking what is going wrong.

Comment: First of all, to add data to your Firebase, you need a class to set Getter/Setter. Have you created the class?

Comment: listeners such as `addOnSuccessListener()` and `addOnFailureListener()`.
In those listeners, try creating a `Toast` of and failure. If it is a failure, try creating a `Toast` or `Log` for `e.getMessage()`. `e` is the `Exception` created by default by the `addOnFailureListener()`. And just check once if the `editText` is empty or not. Firebase will not update if the string is empty

Comment: @SweArmy A class with a getter or setter is not really necessary if it is a single text. A getter or setter is required when you have multiple data and have to declare a class for it. She is just sending a simple text. I already have a firebase project where I send such simple texts and it works fine.

Comment: @SimranSharma is it possible to retrieve data from firebase without getter/setter?

Comment: @SweArmy if it is a single text, then yes. If it is a whole bunch of data, you cannot. Refer to the official documentation for it. Even they have sent a simple text without a class and without a getter or setter. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: You can also write primitive/JSON types, so writing a string should work. Did you attach the listeners mentioned earlier? If so, please edit your question to show the updated code, and its output.

Comment: I noticed something strange in your Gradle implementations. Why have you mentioned the implementation for `com.google.firebase:firebase-database` twice? And that too with different version numbers.

Comment: It is not updating because this is a network related activity so it has to be done in a thread or asynctask (depreciated).

Comment: @ShivanshPotdar No. It is not necessary to do it in a `Thread`. That is just going to complicate the code. The code is right. They have mentioned the library for `firebase-database` twice that too with different version numbers and apart from that, they should check through the listeners what is the reason for the data not being updated. Maybe the security rules are set to read/write true, but only for auth users. Maybe the string is empty. So they should check for those things. Using `Thread`/`AsyncTask` is absolutely useless in this case, in fact, will create unnecessary complications.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly check if your app is connected to firebase or not.

Also, check for the security rules.
You have mentioned that read and write are set to true in the security rules. But are they true for everyone or only for auth users.

You have mentioned `com.google.firebase:firebase-database` twice in your Gradle file that too with different version numbers.
Use BoM, since it does the hard work of using the correct compatible version numbers for firebase libraries themselves.

Then implement the libraries in the Gradle file `buld.gradle (:app)` (app-level) like below:

```
// Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.2.0')

// Declare the dependency for the Firebase library
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
```

And then in your `buttonSave.setOnClickListener()` method, add listeners for success and failure.

```
databaseReference.setValue(username)
    .addOnSuccessListener(Activity.this,new OnSuccessListener<Void>(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid){
            // SUCCESS
 
            // Log the details
            Log.d("FirebaseData","user data uploaded successfully");
            // Make a toast
            Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "user data uploaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }).addOnFailureListener(Activity.this,new OnFailureListener(){
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e){
            // FAILURE
 
            // Log the details
            Log.d("FirebaseData","user data upload failed");
            // Make a toast
            Toast.makeText(Activity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to change your dependencies useing firebase bom it will added all compatatible version regarding firebase

```
 implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.1')
```

then in on click method you try this uding your root firebase db name ,Here users is root db name in firebase

private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            // Write was successful!
           
        }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            // Write failed
           
        }
    });
```